# Segmentation Fault With argv

Tags: c++, c, argv, argc

I have a program that reads in a single argument from the command line and performs certain operations on it. I'm using argv and argc. When I fail to pass an argument to the program, it segfaults. I've tried checking if argc isn't a certain value and then printing the value out, but it still segfaults. Here's the code in question. Note that it works as expected when passed a single argument. Here's the code in question:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

int numTimes = atoi(argv[1]);           //converts content of argv[1] into integer

if(argc != 2)
{
        printf("Enter a valid integer.");
}
```

Comment: `std::vector<std::string> arguments(argv, argv+argc);`

Comment: @MooingDuck: I don't see how that solves the problem.

Comment: @larsmans:  It makes everything easier, and (for some implementations) prevents UB and might have made his error obvious and easy to find.

Comment: @MooingDuck: indexing past the end with `[]` is still UB. You need to use `at` to make this perfectly safe.

Comment: @larsmans: I believe indexing past the end with [] is IB.  I believe it is UB for GCC and VS Release, but well defined for VS Debug.  (my prev comment was initially wrong, I might have corrected after you posted)

Answer (score 7):

You need to check `argc` *before* you try to access that argument.  Just move the `argc` test to sometime before before you call `atoi(argv[1])`.

Answer (score 5):

Just check the number of arguments before trying to accessing a specific element. Something like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{ 

    if(argc < 2)
    { 
        printf("Enter a valid integer."); 
        return 0;
    }

    int numTimes = atoi(argv[1]); // now we're sure to have at least 1 argument passed

    // ...
}
```

Comment: I tried that and it still isn't working. Here's a simplified version:

    #include<stdio.h>
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
    int input = atoi(argv[1]);           //converts content of argv[1] into integer
    if(argc != 2)
    {
            printf("Enter a valid integer.");
    }
    printf("%d", input);
    }
Edit: Sorry for the butchered reply; I'm still getting used to this site.

Comment: You have to check for the correct number of elements (argc) first; THEN try to read the integer.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I though I did exactly what you said, but I missed something. Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 2):

You have to do the check *before* attempting to access the arguments.